# CMS for a site with blog, login, shopping cart, etc

Tags: cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I am in the planning process of a website that will have a blog (as well as other pages which will be static), a login area (so that registered users can access private content), a shopping cart, and possibly later on a forum.

What would be the best CMS to use for all of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favourite is [Drupal](http://drupal.org), technically speaking (some say Joomla! is easier). You can add to it modules like [e-commerce](http://drupal.org/project/ecommerce) , or [Ubercart](http://www.ubercart.org/) (maybe the best). And to make it easy the install, or install it as well in the cloud, or in a vmware for testing or other purposes, I'd grab the free [Bitnami Drupal](http://bitnami.org/stack/drupal) installer.

I think it covers all which you mention (and much more, as counts on tons of free available modules). Is more web coder friendly, and clean than other CMSs around. And is nice for seo.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you aren't looking to spend thousands on license costs you will be picking a CMS based on the Open Source/Free license offerings.

You should consider the latest trends for CMS, because looking at it objectively most CMSs have all the features you need.  It is easy enough to recommend/hate any CMS on the market based on good/bad experiences - but you are better off by starting with a shortlist that:

- a) match your technical skills (if any)
- b) have an active community
- c) are well used and mature
- d) are extensible and should match you present and future needs

This [CMS report by Water and Stone](http://www.waterandstone.com/book/2010-open-source-cms-market-share-report) should be useful in all those regards.

Answer (score 2):

I've had great success with [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/). Granted - it's not built to be a CMS per se`, more designed to be a blogging engine, but it does really well with simple plugins, and even custom one's (if you are a little more PHP ambitious).

I actually work for a nonprofit called [CURE International](http://cure.org), and in the last year me and two other guys (I do HTML, CSS and design, and they do scripting and backend work) have rebuilt our whole site from this really cruddy old CMS all onto Wordpress. Our work even got featured on the [Wordpress showcase](http://wordpress.org/showcase/cure-international/).

It has proved to be VERY extensible. We're taking advantage of the [Blog](http://cure.org/blog/), the Pages features, [User lists](http://cure.org/about/management-team/) for a staff directory, and even built a [completely custom plugin for our CUREkids program](http://cure.org/curekids/), which our reps in the field use to upload photos of kids from our actual hospitals in developing countries.

There is even a very slick plugin for [ecommerce](http://www.instinct.co.nz/e-commerce/) that I've heard wonderful things about. I'm considering it as one of my top two options for relaunching our CURE store later this year.

*To sum it up...*

**PROS**

1. Easy to use and install, both from a server deploy standpoint, and from an admin interface standpoint.
2. Publishing content is very simple and intuitive.
3. There is a VERY large developer community, so updates and bug fixes are fairly quick, and lots of plugins and widgets to extend functionality exist.
4. The CMS is very Google friendly from a markup perspective.
5. For custom functionality that you need but cannot find in anyone's pluggin or tutorial, modification is pretty easy ***IF*** you are comfortable working with PHP
6. Stackexchange even has a dedicated [Q&A site for Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).
7. Arguably the perfect blogging platform for sites that are essentially a blog-style content site.
8. Supports multiple authors for content, users, etc.
9. Even supports multiple sites via Wordpress MU

**CONS**

1. Ultimately the system's strength is blogging, so for more extensive functionality, you have to "add on" to the system via plugins, etc. - which means more items to keep track of updating, etc.

Really can't think of any other cons to Wordpress - honestly I'm a big fan, so of course I have way more positive stuff to say than negatives.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Go for Joomla. Use rockettheme template [ i will configure it for you for free :D] use virtue mart and Login is handled by Joomla itself.
Else
Joomla as site, Open Cart as shopping.Have a happy day